# Why reduce works in different ways with same arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm experimenting with operations on images in Python and I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nych18rsXKU&index=8&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDffXBfcH9ZJuvctJV3OtB8A) (even if it's for Python 2 one can convert it to Python 3 without effort), I brutally copied the code shown in the linked video but I applied it on a  much larger image and PyCharm gave me a warning (but that's not the problem we are discussing), so I tried a different method (as slow but without the warnings) but it didn't work the same way.

Trying to understand why I began experimenting/debugging and here's what I found out:

The first image's pixel is [114, 121, 127] and here's how it should work properly with an handmade array (both `print` give the correct result: **362**):

```
print(114 + 121 + 127)
lista = np.array([114, 121, 127])
print(lista, ":\n", reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, lista))
```

So here `reduce` works properly.

BUT: the same exact `reduce` operation done on the same exact array not handmade but obtained from the image gives me **106**, and that doesn't make sense; here's the debugging code:

```
from functools import reduce
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

f = Image.open("CastelloCol.jpg")
img = np.array(f)
f.close()

k = 0
max = 5
for row in img:
    for pixel in row:
        avg = 0
        for i in range(3):  # manual sum of RGB channels
            avg += pixel[i]
            print(pixel[i], end=" ")
        print(":\n", avg, "\n")  # prints correct result

        print(pixel, ":")  # reduce sum of RGB channels
        print(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, pixel), "\n")  # prints wrong result
        k += 1
        if k >= max:  # prints only the first max pixels
            break
    if k >= max:
        break
```

So the question is: why does `reduce` give me those nonsensical results? What did I get wrong?

Answered

Comment: Reduce iterates on the "sequence" parameter, so the question would be: what do you get if you iterate on `pixel` in the first loop instead of iterating on `range(3)` and getting the item at that index? I expect whatever `pixel` is it has a specific behaviour when iterated which differs from being simply indexed. You can also try feeding the pixel to `sum()` and checking which one of the two cases it results in (I expect reduce's).

Comment: @Masklinn : `pixel` is an array with RGB channels (so 3 values) that represent a pixel of an image. I don't understand what do you mean with "what do you get if you iterate on `pixel` in the first loop instead of iterating on `range(3)`": you obviously get the sigle values of the array.

Comment: So then the arguments are not the same...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : What? They are: `reduce` applies an operation (in this case a sum) on all element of a list or array and that `for loop` applies a sum on all elements of a list or array, so if the list or array is the same then the arguments are the same (and comparing the first example I posted with the second you can see the ARE the same).

Comment: They are not the same array, dude. Try to think what could be different. Hint: look at the dtypes. Printing the object is about the lowest bar you can go for investigating this.

Comment: IOW, "The first image's pixel is [114, 121, 127] " is absolutely incorrect. That is a list literal, not a numpy ndarray, and won't behave the same. More importantly, the array you create here: `np.array([114, 121, 127])` is not the same array referenced by `pixel`, they have *different dtypes* with different acceptable numeric ranges.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : Ok, thanks, but why they should behave differently with the same operation on their values if their values are the same? It's not like I'm trying to sum an int with a string.

Comment: **they are not the same dtypes**. Just see what happens for yourself when you manually sum `np.uint8` objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: In other words: does `reduce` take the first value, sum it with the second,then take the result and sum it to the third? Are the first, the second and the third values 114, 121, 127? If they are then why the result is 106? If not then why printing the values gives those numbers and why doing a sum for each values give a different result?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry: I didn't see your last comment, so the problem is that 141 + 121 + 127 are calculated like uint8 (so [0, 255] interval) and even the result is considered uint8 so, since the result exceeds 255 it is incorrect?

Comment: Yes. You are working with `uint8`. Not *like uint8*. They *are uint8*. This is simply [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). Notice, `362 % 256 == 106`

Comment: As an aside, `reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, iterable)` should just be `sum(iterable)` to begin with...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Ok, thanks. About `sum(iterables)`: yes, you are right, but it was just a mere copy of the code in the video and when I noticed the sum error I tried to understand why without thinking for a way to do it better.

Comment: Now, how do I flag it as answered?

Comment: The best way would be for juanpa.arrivillaga to collect their comments as an answer so you can flag it, it's possible to convert answers to comments but not the other way around IIRC.